# How to handle an Image that is null in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have this working code that displays an image in the other form when datagridview is selected

```
Private Sub dgv1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv1.DoubleClick
            frmEdit.Show()
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream(changephoto(CInt(dgv1.SelectedCells(0).Value)))
            frmEdit.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End Sub


        Function changephoto(ByVal photo As Integer) As Byte()
            cn.Open()

            With cmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "SELECT studImage FROM studentInformation WHERE Studentid = " & dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
            End With
            Dim myPhoto() As Byte = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
            cn.Close()
            Return myPhoto
        End Function
```

The problem is when i select a record that has no image,I get  this error:

[image: Error]
I want the user to select records even if it is no image in the database without having error. Can anyone help me how to fix this. thanks

Comment: try like this - http://hastebin.com/bajasiliwo.vbs

Comment: @wingedpanther How can i apply that to my code that even it has no image, it will not produce no error?

Comment: What you want to do if there is no image?? a guess show a message that says _"No Photo is defined"_ ?

Comment: Check this - http://hastebin.com/uyuvojimir.vbs (_untested_)

Comment: @wingedpanther I want the user to can still select records even if it is no image in the database without having error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decalre myPhoto() outside of the Try...Catch block. Additionally you should close the connection in error and non-error case (Finally or alternatively with the Using keyword).

```
Dim myPhoto() as Byte = Nothing
With cmd
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "SELECT studImage FROM studentInformation WHERE Studentid = " & dgv1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
End With

Try
  cn.Open()
  myPhoto = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
Catch ex as Exception

Finally
  If cn IsNot Nothing
     cn.Close()
  End If
End Try
return myPhoto
```

EDIT:

```
Private Sub dgv1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgv1.DoubleClick
    frmEdit.Show()
    Dim ms As MemoryStream
    Dim photo as Byte() = changephoto(CInt(dgv1.SelectedCells(0).Value))
    If photo IsNot Nothing
       ms = new MemoryStream(photo)
       frmEdit.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for commenting but using your code i get different error now. It says **ArgumentNullException was unhandled.
Buffer cannot be a null**

Comment: Dim ms As New MemoryStream(changephoto(CInt(dgv1.SelectedCells(0).Value))) This line

Comment: This loc is not in your example thus I don´t know what your trying to do. My guess is that you have to check the return value of function `changephoto` for null values after you called it.

Comment: That code is in my example at the top inside the Private Sub dgv1_DoubleClick -  line 2

Comment: See my edit. You have to handle null values before setting your picture.